# Angular 4 Total sum

Tags: angular

I have this

```
    lists = [
    {
        name: 'Картошка',
        cost: 20,
        checked: false,
    },
    {
        name: 'Хлеб',
        cost: 10,
        checked: false,
    }
    ];

    cart = [];

    check(list: any){
        list.checked = !list.checked
        if(list.checked) {
            this.cart.push(list.cost);
        } else{

        }
        console.log(this.cart); 
    }
```

Please help. When click on checkbox(true), add cost to totalSum. And when checkbox(false) delete cost from totalSum. I dont know how made it. Please help. Thanks!
How made it?

Comment: How did it go with the answers, did either help you? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `[ngModel]` and `ngModelChange()` to handle this as below,

```
<div *ngFor= "let list of lists" >
    <input type="checkbox" (ngModelChange)="check($event,list)"
          [ngModel]="list.checked" />{{list?.name}}

</div>


check(status,list: any){
        if(status) {
            this.cart.push(list.cost);
        } 
        console.log(this.cart); 
}
```

Note: Handling of the else part is not done.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4aSx7Pd87R27RrwHlkM4?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total sum, I'd not use an array, but a variable, for example named `totalSum`

```
totalSum = 0;
```

in your iteration, do as Aravind suggested and use `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`:

```html
<div *ngFor= "let list of lists" >
  <input type="checkbox" (ngModelChange)="check($event, list.cost)"
          [ngModel]="list.checked" />{{list.name}}
</div>
```

Then your `check` method would look like this:

```ts
check(isChecked, cost){
  if(isChecked) {
    this.totalSum += cost;
  } else {
    this.totalSum -= cost;
  }
}
```

where we simply check if the checkbox is checked, if so, add to the total sum, if not, subtract the value from `totalSum`.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4jxwjTBtDp91lqHIAGGd?p=preview)**